# IOS file upload encountering stream error

Tags: ios, file-upload, parse-platform

I use Parse as backend and create a IOS app for uploading images.

When I upload using the WIFI network there is no problem, but I am encountering a file upload error when using 4g/3g network.

```
Encountered stream error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=54 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection reset by peer"
```

Although I catch the error in the code but the alert view didn't show up, it shows "upload fail" only in the log.

```
    PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:fileData];
[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"An error occured!" message:@"Please try submiting your item again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
```

The data in the backend looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, for successful upload the file name is image.jpg, for unsuccessful ones, it shows unknow string.

Answer (score -1):

It could be your Network problem, can you please ensure the speed for your network is fine? There shouldn't be any problem regardless what kind of network you use unless it is slow and it causes timeout for the function.

Before the upload function, can I see the code that you written to process the file?